# Label Does not display in c# window form App

Tags: c#, winforms

i am using this code but it display just newlabelName

```
        foreach (var type in obj.sType)
        {
            Label newLabelForName = new Label
            {
                Text = type.sName,
                Font = new Font("Arial", 16),
                AutoSize = false,
                BackColor = Color.Red,
                Width = formObject.panelDetail.Width
            };
            Label newLabelForPrice = new Label
            {
                Text = "Price : " + type.fPrice ,
                Font = new Font("Arial", 16),
            };
            Label newLabelForQuantity = new Label
            {
                Text = "Quantity : " + type.sQuantity,//newLabelForName.Text + Environment.NewLine + newLabelForPrice,
                Font = new Font("Arial", 16)

            };
            formObject.panelDetail.Controls.Add(newLabelForName);
            formObject.panelDetail.Controls.Add(newLabelForPrice);
            formObject.panelDetail.Controls.Add(newLabelForQuantity);

        }
```

sType is array of object within object i use sName,fPrice and sQuantity

Comment: You need to specify Size and Location properties of  these Label Controls. In your current code Label Controls are being added to Panel, since their Location and Size is not specified Label Controls are shown on top of each other.

Comment: no working............

Comment: You need to explain how it is "no working"? You receive an exception? What else did you try?

Comment: Label newLabelForPrice = new Label
                {
                    Location = new Point(100, 500),
                    Size = new Size(200, 32),
                    AutoSize = false,
                    Text = "Price : " + type.fPrice,
                    Font = new Font("Arial", 16)
                };

Comment: If you don't know the size, then you can use `AutoSize`

Comment: yes you right these control shown on top of each other any to get next to previous label location